# Multiply column with same content, make them count as "one"

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, count

**About**

I have this table in my database holding some information saved with a user id and time.

```
| CONTENT | USER ID | TIME       |
| text    | 1       | 1405085592 |
| hello   | 2       | 1405085683 |
| hey     | 1       | 1405086953 |
```

This example could be a data dump from my database, now as you can count there is "three" rows. However I only need to know how many users there have some information in my database. Therefor the result I'm really looking for is "two", because only two users have information in the database. User ID 1 is owning both "text"(1) & "hey"(3) where user ID 2 haves "hello"(2).

**In short**

I want to count how many users (regardless how many rows of information they have) there are inside my database.

** What I tried **

I tried to fetch every single row into an array and then using `array_unique` to count them together, works fine but I do not see this as a clean and best way to do this.

**Then what?**

I could use the `array_unique` and just use `count` to see how many rows there are, but I'm looking for something more clean. I tried to search for this, but I'm not actually sure what I should search for in term to hit something I'm looking for. After being stuck and though I wanted to learn something new, I wanted to post this problem here.

**Note**

I hope you guys can help me, I have tried to make it clear what I'm looking for and what I tried. If not please let me know. Sorry if some of the above contains misspelled words, incorrect grammar or is badly explained. I do not speak English daily, but I try my best.

Comment: Typically one would have a separate users table, to which the `USER ID` column refers.

Comment: @eggyal Normally i would do this as so, but because of the way i need to complete my project i do not need any storage of a user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the `DISTINCT` keyword. It returns the count of unique values of a column:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id)
FROM your_table
```

See example on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/86429/1).

Answer (score 0):

This query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM table
```

will return just one row for every user in the table.